# Eliminate (multiple) sub-domains via RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm trying to eliminate (what is sometimes multiple) sub-domains from a list so I am left with only the domain name plus the TLD or ccTLD

Example data in...

```
something1.something2.example.com
something3.something3.example.co.uk
www.example.net
random.something.else.example.cc
```

Example data output...

```
example.com
example.co.uk
example.net
example.cc
```

What I've tried...

```
^.*(?!(?<=\.))\..*\.{2,3}$
```

Is there a function or better (working) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to match the data in question, don't bother matching from the start of the line :

```
[^.]*(\.[^.]{2,3}){1,2}$
```

Try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yB8uC0/1).

If you want to replace the lines, group all that and select everything from the start of the line :

```
^.*?([^.]*(\.[^.]{2,3}){1,2})$
```

Then replace with the first back-reference.

Try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aG0nW1/1).

Note that there is no way to distinguish a 3 letters or less domain name from a ccTLD (unless you want to list them all), so it might fail to bring up the correct data on these ones.
For example, with "this.may.bug.com" it will match "may.bug.com" instead of the expected "bug.com".

Comment: ok, this is close, but perhaps I wasn't clear, I want to "select" with regex the extra sub-domains (so I can delete them) and keep/leave the domain and TLD.  So basically the exact opposite of what your regex does.

Comment: @user3769418 Check my second regex101 example, it does exactly what you want (but not in the way you said it in this comment).

Comment: Humm, your right, but I was hoping to do a find [regex statement] and replace with [blank] in notepad2 or similar so I could have it eliminate the first part.  I guess I need to learn how the substitution /1 thing works and if I can do something similar in notepad2

Comment: I don't know notepad2 but it's `\1` not `/1`, and it's called a back-reference. If `\1` does not work you could maybe try `$1`.

Comment: @user3769418 If all fails you can use `^.*?(?=[^.]+(\.[^.]{2,3}){1,2}$)` and replace with blank

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks a ton!